# installation failed : could not copy folder in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, macos, woocommerce, xampp, wordpress-theming

well I am trying to download and install the woocommerce plugin on my Wordpress which is located in my personal system and local host . I'm having issues for fixing this problem .do you guys have any advice for me?

I searched too much but I didn't find any useful solution given that some people were using Wordpress on a real host but I am using it on XAMPP and my OS is Mac .

Answer (score 0):

try to download the woo-commerce plugin as a zipped file, then extract it into the directory of plugins in the WordPress content folder directly.